# Error print the message

Tags: linux, bash, git, github

## Approach

I have ang script and which performs file aggregation by extension, create a commit and upload with push. 
This is :

```
function LsAddCm () {

echo -e 'Enter the extension'
read rExtension
# AEFO-Started : #Audio-WB Creación de 'AEFO_00SL_AudioWB/'
# CM1 => AEFO-Started : 
echo -e 'Enter the first part [ AEFO-Started : ]'
read CM1
# CM2 => #Audio-WB 
echo -e 'Enter the second part [ #Audio-WB ]'
read CM2
# CM3 => Creación de {...}
echo -e 'Enter the third part [ Creación de ]'
read CM3
#message="AEFO-Started : #Audio-WB Creación de "
echo "'${CM1}' '${CM2}' '${CM3}'"
time ls |  awk -F . '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'git add $1.'${rExtension}' && git commit -m "'${CM1}' '${CM2}' '${CM3}' $1.'${rExtension}'" && git push' sh

}
# Execute the program, in anothers words, runnning the function necesary

function run (){

    echo run ✅
    LsAddCm
}

run
```

## Problem

The problem is when I want to put a variable as a message and a space is introduced while is executig the output is :

```
$ sh s1.sh
run ✅
Enter the extension
mp3
Enter the first part [ AEFO-Started : ]
A 1
Enter the second part [ #Audio-WB ]
A 2
Enter the third part [ Creación de ]
A 3
'A 1' 'A 2' 'A 3'
1 A: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
1 A: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
1 A: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
1 A: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
1 A: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
1 A: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

real    0m0,899s
user    0m0,061s
sys     0m0,447s
```

## Question

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Quote your variables! `${CM1}` → `"${CM1}"`, etc. https://www.shellcheck.net is your friend.

Comment: I tried it as `and" next to 'but nothing ...

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re saying, but I’m fairly sure quoting the variables will solve the issue.

Comment: …I can produce a similar error with `foo='bar baz' ; sh -c 'echo "'${foo}'"'`, and solve it with `foo='bar baz' ; sh -c 'echo "'"${foo}"'"'`.

Comment: I can try it ... Thanks

Comment: It does not work ... The same @Biffen

Comment: Could you compress this to a [mcve]?

Comment: The problem is If I delete the code, it will not be understood. I check it later

Comment: Your function `LsAddCm` uses `$1` but you do not supply any parameters (does no solve your problem though).

Comment: @NicolásAlarcónR. I've tried your code (verbatim), I get the same errors and quoting *all* the variables *does solve the error*: `time ls |  awk -F . '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'git add $1.'"${rExtension}"' && git commit -m "'"${CM1}"' '"${CM2}"' '"${CM3}"' $1.'"${rExtension}"'" && git push' sh`

Comment: @Biffen Perfect !!! Very good !! This is the solution .. Can you answer the answer with that solution and I will give it as valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution ( Correction )

**Quoting all the variables does solve the error**, an other words, to print correctly you must correct the following line:

```
time ls |  awk -F . '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'git add $1.'${rExtension}' && git commit -m "'${CM1}' '${CM2}' '${CM3}' $1.'${rExtension}'" && git push' sh
```

by following :

```
time ls | awk -F . '{print $1}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'git add $1.'"${rExtension}"' && git commit -m "'"${CM1}"' '"${CM2}"' '"${CM3}"' $1.'"${rExtension}"'" && git push' sh
```